# Differentiating between custom and default functions while using MATLAB `help`

Tags: matlab

I am trying to figure out how to use a certain package in `MATLAB`. Is it possible to differentiate between the custom functions in the package and the default functions while displaying information with `help`? In other words, when I do `help functionName`, is it possible that I also get the information of whether or not that function is a default one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`which`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) to differentiate.

Built-in functions are prefixed with `'built-in'` using `which`. These can run via the [`builtin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html) function.